How to generate href-links containing '#' with ThymeLeaf?
in my template, I must generate a link of type
<a href="http://myhost/myapp/#/products/12345/details">. . .</a>

'12345' is a variable part.
The link is a "deep link" to details of the product with the ID=12345. The '#' in the URL must be there because the web framework that displays the details wants it so (I think it's a single page web app).
If I have this in the template:
<a th:href="@{http://myhost/myapp/#/products/{productId}/details(productId=${product.id})}">. . .</a>

then the generated link looks like
.../myapp?productId=12345#/products/{productId}/details

i.e. the part beginning with '#' is fist cut off and then appended verbatim; the parameter is appended to the URL as a query string (with '?').
If I have this in the template (i.e. I make the hash symbol part of the variable so that this part of th URL is not cut off):
<a th:with="productLink=${'#/products/' + product.id + '/details'}"
   th:href="@{http://myhost/myapp/{productLink}(productLink=${productLink})}">. . .</a>

then I get almost what I want, but the '#' in the URL is encoded as '%23':
<a href="http://myhost/myapp/%23/products/12345/details">. . .</a>

How can I generate the URL as it should be, i.e. with the hash sign and the product id at correct place -- see the start of the question.
The application is a SpringBoot based one, if that matters.

did you try your link before , in browser and it was allowed ?

What link do you mean? The one I'd like to generate? Yes, I did try it, and it works. My goal is valid.

If you don't want Thymeleaf to mess with your URL, I would suggest using the regular string functions.  You could use literal substitution for example:
<a th:href="|http://myhost/myapp/#/products/${product.id}/details|">. . .</a>

(Here is why Thymeleaf is messing with your #.  It's trying to keep the # at the end of the url.  I don't believe there is any way to change how this is working.)

Thank you! In the meantime, I've also come up with a solution, but yours is simpler. My solution was to create a custom LinkBuilder and register it within the template engine. The custom LinkBuilder does not implement a sophisticated logics to preserve URL fragments, but that's exactly what I want. My solution is a little bit more robust because the custom LinkBuilder still URL-encodes the path segments.

You can use javascript to solve this issue, i don't think ThymeLeaf will allow it in href with @ signe :
give it a class to access it :
<a 
class=" link-requires-fixing " // add your class here
th:href="@{http://myhost/myapp/#/products/{productId}/details(productId=${product.id})}">. . .</a>


then change href attribute
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

   const linksToFix = document.querySelectorAll(".link-requires-fixing");

    linksToFix.forEach(link => {
      const originalHref = link.getAttribute("href");
      const updatedHref = originalHref ? originalHref.replace("%23", "#") : "";
      link.setAttribute("href", updatedHref);
    });

  
});


Thank you for the reply, but if it's the only way to accomplish what I need then thymeleaf is a wrong framework for me. Simple things should be simple. Is there a way without the @-expression?
